# Qt Creator - C++ Library, No executable found?

Tags: c++, qt

So im a bit confused by what to-do with this current pop-up im having from QT. Not entirely sure what it means. 
So i'm trying to  create a C++ Library, as a static linked library. Currently the library has no code in it whatsoever. 
Immediately hitting the build button to make sure everything runs fine the following pop-up below is displayed.

Im not sure what this means exactly. Or indeed, why it is even being shown in the first place. building any of my other project files works fine without issue. But this does not.

[image: The Pop-Up].

As for what i have, i am using the Qt SDK, version 4.8.1. 
Any help solving this issue would be greatly appreciated :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A library [usually] needs to be invoked from an executable - The dialog box you are seeing is asking you to specify an executable that will bring your library into life and call functions within it.

You need to write a client executable (or use an existing executable) to use your library and specify the path in this dialog box.

Comment: I've never actually used a library before (you can properly tell :P), so i'm still slightly confused. The "client executable", what would then need to be exactly?

Comment: it'd be a Qt project of type console application  - anything which can actually load your library and call functionality in it

Comment: @alexisdm is probably more correct in observing that you have tried to run the library rather than build it.

Comment: @Danran Like python?

Answer (score 1):

The button you clicked was probably the Run button:
[image: QtCreator Run icon]
, not the build button: [image: QtCreator Build icon].